# Can't enable Hyper-V Platform in control panel

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I installed windows 8 pro and i want to use visual studio  for windows phone development.But i can't do that.

You can find my processor detail at http://products.amd.com/en-us/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=407

I have enabled the virtualization technology in motherboard.But i can't make it.Please help me.

Note:

I can enable "Hyper - V" But not "Hyper V Platform",

My question is, whether i need to enable the "Hyper V platform" option for the windows 8 phone emulator.

Please suggest me!

Comment: Seems like an exact duplicate of this: http://superuser.com/q/568425/9232

Comment: I've checked that link already and mentioned that i enabled in bios configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your CPU does not support SLAT.

Take a look: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/olivnie/archive/2013/01/18/hyper-v-on-client-windows-8-pro.aspx